# In IPython console (Spyder), can I access a variable from main() after running my program?

Tags: python, ipython

I am running my code using an IPython Console. I have a `main()` function that is executed as follows:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":  
    main()
```

Then `main()` calls a bunch of other functions and I don't use any classes.
My question is, can I print or manipulate my variables interactively in the console after running my program?

Like if I don't have `main()` or any other functions, for example I can declare in my code:

```
a=1
```

And then it is easy to access from the console:

```
In [20]: a

Out[20]: 1
```

Thank you in advance if you can help with this noob question.

Answer (score 3):

Have `main` return `locals()`.

```
def main():
    # ...
    return locals()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    locals().update(main())
```

See also [Making function variables from imported module available in iPython interactive namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28432412/making-function-variables-from-imported-module-available-in-ipython-interactive/41861848#41861848) and [Dump function variables to workspace in python/ipython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26830141/dump-function-variables-to-workspace-in-python-ipython/41861891#41861891)